# Example of a ‘weak’ ideal which is not an ideal?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

For Hilbert spaces $H$ and $K$, let $V=B(H,K)(H \neq K)$. A sub space $I$ of $V$ is called an ideal of $V$ if $$IV^*V+VV^*I \subset I$$ and $I$ is called weak ideal of $V$ If $$\text{span}\{IV^*V-VV^*I\} \subset I$$ It is clear that every ideal is weak ideal.

> Does there exist a weak ideal of $B(H,K)$ which is not an ideal?

I was trying to construct example from rectangular matrices by having trace in mind but could not get any idea. Any ideas to construct such ideal?

P.S. This question was first posted on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4036680/looking-for-an-example-of-weak-ideal) but I did not get any answer there.

Comment: So $H,K$ are Hilbert spaces?  I think you must have made a mistake: if $H,K$ are both separable infinite dimensional (for example) and $V = B(H,K)$ then $V^*V = B(H)$ and $VV^* = B(K)$.  Is $I$ means to be a subspace of $B(H,K)$?

Comment: @MatthewDaws I think this must all be TRO related, and I suspect the OP has taken definitions pertaining to general TROs and tried to specialize to particular cases. To the OP: perhaps you could give references for the definitions you are presenting here?

Comment: @YemonChoi: I don’t have references for the ‘weak’ ideal definition, it’s something i am trying to define. As far as ideal is concerned, it’s usually known as TRO ideal.

Comment: @MatthewDaws: Sorry you’re right, I means to be sub space of B(H,K).

Comment: Even with the edit, $V$ is still defined to be the whole of $B(H,K)$.  This is surely too strong a condition.  Do you perhaps want $V$ to be a TRO?

Comment: @MatthewDaws: In general, the same could be defined for any TRO $V$ but I was wondering if there is some example for the TRO B(H,K). Do you have example of weak ideal for some TRO $V$ other than $B(H,K)$?

Comment: Actually, I don't understand the notation, because when you write something like "$V^*V$" I take this to be _defined to be_ a linear span, namely $\operatorname{span}\{ x^*y : x,y\in V \}$.  So I don't understand the difference in definition between "ideal" and "weak ideal".

Comment: @MatthewDaws: Sorry, by taking product of definition as yours did you mean   span$(IV^*V-VV*I)=IV^*V-VV^*I$? I don’t see it. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @ArpitKansal  I was trying to understand what the OP meant by what they wrote...

Comment: @MatthewDaws: Unfortunately the OP hasn’t replied but assuming the ‘usual’ understanding of product do you think both concepts coincide? Even after trying hard, I could get a counterexample.

Comment: I think you should ask a new question, being very precise about what your question is.